# Command line GIT logging with different colors

Tags: git

I have color turned on in my git configuration. I find the log --decorate very useful, however it does not give me all the information I need.

Basically, if I run `git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all` I see a nice list of commits, with tags, and branches colored differently (current head cyan, remote branches red, local branches green, tags yellow on my system).

I find the colored refs handy to see what branch is in what state. However, I also need to know the commiter and commit date. So I'm come up with the following:

```
git log --graph --pretty=format:'%C(white bold)%h %Cblue%cn %Cred%cr %C(cyan)%d %Creset%s'
```

But, this looses the differences in color between the different refnames (all coming out cyan, as expected based ont eh command `...%C(cyan)%d...`).

Does anyone know how to reset the refnames to use the coloring as defined in the gitconfig?? Something like `...%C(auto)%d...`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible in the current version of git, but it looks like a feature like this [will be added in git 2.0](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/222085/):

> - pretty: add %C(auto) for auto-coloring